# Mapstruct qualifiedByName multi parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, mapper

[createMeaDto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV2zQ.png)

[mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH3Io.png)

[mapperImpl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1T8L.png)

```
@Named("createMealToEntity")
@Mapping(source = "restaurantId", target = "restaurantId")
@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "mealId")
Meal createMealToEntity(CreateMealDto createMealDto,String restaurantId);

@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "createMealToEntity")
List<Meal> createListMealToEntity(List<CreateMealDto> createMealDtoList, String restaurantId);
```

I need to overload list of objects to an object with paramter.

Comment: can u add code instead of screenshots? and provide more details on the same.

Comment: like @AshishSharma said, please don't post text as images. Images are inaccessible by search engines and people with disabilities. Also we can't copy &paste, while the post requires unnecessary bandwidth, just to name a few of the many drawbacks

Answer (score 0):

Maper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MealMapper {


@Named("createMealToEntity")
@Mapping(source = "restaurantId", target = "restaurantId")
@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "mealId")
Meal createMealToEntity(CreateMealDto createMealDto,String restaurantId);

@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "createMealToEntity")
List<Meal> createListMealToEntity(List<CreateMealDto> createMealDtoList, String restaurantId);

List<MealDto> entityToDto(List<Meal> mealList);
}
```

CreateMealDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CreateMealDto {
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String ingredients;
    private Double timeToDo;
}
```

Meal

```
public class Meal {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "meal_id")
private String mealId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "price")
private Double price;

@Column(name = "image_url")
private String imageUrl;

@Column(name = "ingredients")
private String ingredients;

@Column(name = "time_to_do")
private Double timeToDo;

@Column(name = "restaurant_id")
private String restaurantId;
}
```